# Does calling a numpy function in a vectorized operation affect performance?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am new to `python` and currently studying the `numPy` package. I come from the `C/C++` world, so maybe my question is stupid. When using vectorized operations in `numPy`, I assume that they parallelize the execution like `openMP` does.

I came across a piece of code in an udacity tutorial, which calculated a standardized 1D-array in the following way:

```
standardized = (array - array.mean()) / array.std()
```

where array is a `numPy` array. So in my eyes `numPy` would parallelize the following 'single' instructions to get a better performance:

```
standardized[0] = (array[0] - array.mean()) / array.std()
standardized[1] = (array[1] - array.mean()) / array.std()
...
...
standardized[n] = (array[n] - array.mean()) / array.std()
```

where `n` is the size of the `array`. So in every iteration, I would call `mean()` and `std()` which gets always calculated and therefore needs a lot of time. In a `'C way'` I would do something like this, to increase performance:

```
mean = array.mean()
std = array.std()
standardized = (array - mean) / std
```

I measured times for both calculations and nearly got always the same time. In fact, it depends on which method I use first, which is the fastest. Additionally, I only used array filled with zeros, maybe this has an impact, too.

So my question is, how does `python` (or `numPy`) 'parallalize' the vectorized execution and how does it deal with function calls, which should always return the same value in one iteration.

I hope my questions are clear and understandable. I could not find any sources which deals with this use-case.

Comment: That is not how it works, `(array[1] - array.mean()) / array.std()` is equivalent to the version you had with intermediate `mean` and `std` variables. In both versions, `array.mean()` and `array.std()` get calculated once. `numpy` doesn't do anything magic with the python-level code.

Comment: So how does python(numPy) "know" that it only has to calculate it once? I know the value doesn't change, but what if they could?

Comment: `numpy` doesn't, it's simply equivalent at the python bytecode level, before it ever gets to `numpy`

Comment: use the dissasembler, `import dis` then check out `dis.dis('standardized = (array - array.mean()) / array.std()')` and `dis.dis('mean = array.mean()\nstd = array.std()\nstandardized = (array - mean) / std')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
standardized = (array - array.mean()) / array.std()
```

is a Python expression which gets evaluated as:

```
temp1 = array.mean()     
temp2 = array.std()
temp3 = (array - temp1)
temp4 = temp3 / temp2
```

`array.mean` is a numpy 'builtin' method, which means it's written in compiled code.  Same for `std`.  And for subtraction and division of two arrays.

`numpy` provides building blocks, python provides the glue to join them together.  Generally the best strategy is to maximize the use of those numpy methods.  And avoid loops at the Python level.  Sometimes a few loops on a complex operation is better, and sometimes using basic Python is better (creating an array from lists takes time).

There are tools for building custom compiled blocks - `cython`, `numba` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any OpenMP-style parallelization in numpy. Speed-gains come from using C/Fortran/specialised libraries such as LAPack/BLAS etc. You can roll your own parallelization using multiprocessing if you can afford the marshaling cost.

There seems to be a way to enable OpenMP if you build yourself: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/linux.html

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear enough. It's not about my numPy implementation, but how numPy implements the "faster code" or "parallelization" which python has not itself. The things I know, is that numPy is written in C and can use "native" C loops instead of slow "python loops"

Comment: I understood your question. What I mean is that the speed gains over pure python are just because of more efficient code, *not* parallelisation. At least that's how it appears to be the case for the default distribution. Building numpy from scratch seems to allow for OpenMP utilisation. But probably within limits. E.g. if you pass a function to numpy  that is then applied to plenty of elements, this can't and won't be parallelized because of the GIL.